# <p:calendar>'s button icon disappeared after applying custom css

Tags: jquery, primefaces, calendar

In my application I am using `<p:calendar showOn="button".......>` and I apply custom css on this calendar with the help of this link: [Bluefoot-CustomCss-Primefaces-Calendar](http://bluefoot.info/howtos/primefaces-calendar-highlight-dates).  After applying this custom css, all is working fine, except the calendar icon turned into `...`. But I want to show that `calendar` icon. How is it possible ? I have attached the picture for better understanding my problem .

One more thing for my case html DOM tree looks like `<button class="ui-datepicker-trigger" type="button">...</button>` where by default this should be

```
<button class="ui-datepicker-trigger ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span>
   <span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span>
</button>
```

I don't know how to solve this. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks,
![image] .

EDIT:1
I am calling this js method before each date show:

```
function applyCustomCssOnCalendar(isAccessable, isAdmin, publicHolidaysAsString, paidLeavesAsString, rttLeavesAsString, specialLeavesAsString, pendingLeavesAsString, pendingLabel, paidLeave) {
$(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay",
        function(date) {

            return highlightCalendar(isAccessable, isAdmin, publicHolidaysAsString, paidLeavesAsString,
                    rttLeavesAsString, specialLeavesAsString, pendingLeavesAsString, pendingLabel, paidLeave, date);
        })
  };
```

applyCustomCssOnCalendar(isAccessable, isAdmin, publicHolidaysAsString, paidLeavesAsString, rttLeavesAsString, specialLeavesAsString, pendingLeavesAsString, pendingLabel, paidLeave) method is defined as :

```
function highlightCalendar(isAccessable, isAdmin, publicHolidaysAsString, paidLeavesAsString, rttLeavesAsString, specialLeavesAsString, pendingLeavesAsString, pendingLabel, paidLeave, datee) {
var date = new Date(datee);
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var y = date.getFullYear();
var day = date.getDay();

var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log(publicHolidaysAsString);

if (day == 6 || day == 0) {
    return [true,'ui-datepicker-unselectable',''];
}   

for ( var i = 0; i < publicHolidaysAsString.length; i = i + 2) {
    if ((y + '-' + m + '-' + d) == publicHolidaysAsString[i]) {
        return [true,'highlight-calendar-publicHoliday ui-datepicker-unselectable',publicHolidaysAsString[i + 1]];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Create fiddle, will help you

Comment: could you show us what are you doing?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal OP's problem is related to Primefaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code as:

```
function applyCustomCssOnCalendar(isAccessable, isAdmin, publicHolidaysAsString, paidLeavesAsString, rttLeavesAsString, specialLeavesAsString, pendingLeavesAsString, pendingLabel, paidLeave) {
    $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay",
        function(date) {
            return highlightCalendar(isAccessable, isAdmin, publicHolidaysAsString, paidLeavesAsString,
                    rttLeavesAsString, specialLeavesAsString, pendingLeavesAsString, pendingLabel, paidLeave, date);
    }).siblings(".ui-datepicker-trigger:button").html("").addClass("ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only").append('<span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span><span class="ui-button-text">ui-button</span>');
};
```

It should work. Since you are calling `beforeShowDay` on your own, the Primefaces' default `beforeShowDay` is not working for your case and this is the reason you are unable to see the `<span/>`. The aforementioned code will add the `<span/>` as Primefaces does.